# Swagger Model Schema Response: alternate label for LocalDate in SpringFox

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

We are using Swagger 2.x and SpringFox 2.0 to document our REST service created with Spring MVC.

We have a REST response with a property List<LocalDate> dates.

In the Model Schema of the response, the label for dates is shown as 'LocalDate'. That is not intended: we would like to have 'date' or 'yyyy-MM-dd' instead.

We have this class:

```
public class SayHelloResponse {

    private List<LocalDate> dates;

    private String message;

    public SayHelloResponse(String message, LocalDate... dates) {
        this.message = message;
        this.dates = ImmutableList.copyOf(dates);
    }

    public List<LocalDate> getDates() {
        return dates;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

That results in this Model Schema:

```
{
  "dates": [
     "LocalDate"
  ],
  "message": "string"
}
```

In the Model Schema, I would like to have LocalDate as 'date' or 'yyyy-MM-dd'. The way to do this seems to be with com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty but this does not have any effect (it is being picked up, as when I add @ApiModelProperty(hidden=true) it is hidden).

I created a [sample rest project](https://bitbucket.org/squins/springmvc-swagger-issues) that shows the issue.

Any ideas how I can change LocalDate to 'date' or 'yyyy-MM-dd' in the Model Schema of Swagger?

Comment: Not sure if its a swagger UI issue or if its just the fact that springfox doesnt support defaults. If there isnt one already, I'd say create an issue for this so that we can provide a default.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in Docket object to replace models called directModelSubstitute(). You can use it like this to substitute LocalDate to Date object:

`Docket#directModelSubstitute(LocalDate.class, Date.class)`

The only problem with it that I found is that you can't change the date format.

See [A/Q section in the official Springfox documentation](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#answers-to-common-questions-and-problems), specifically question "**How do we use Java 8 types esply. LocalDateTime?**"

Answer (score 0):

This is recommended in the official Springfox documentation, but doesn't effect:

```
Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)..build().directModelSubstitute(LocalDate.class, java.sql.Date.class)
```

This effect but change format to date-time instead of date:

```
Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)..build().directModelSubstitute(LocalDate.class, java.util.Date.class);
```

That's why I use the last one and ignore time part.